# Loop through ansible hosts based on play

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible

I have seen the ability to loop through the addresses of the inventory file by doing something like the following:

```
{% for url in groups['kafka'] %}
  {%- if url == ansible_fqdn or url in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
     or ( kafka_id is defined and loop.index0 == kafka_id | int ) -%}
        broker.id={{loop.index0}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem with this idea is I have several different "Kafa" type hosts each that will do something slightly different. I am wondering if there is a way I can pass the variable for **groups['kafka']** through the playbook rather than hardcoding it in the template. This way I am only using the hosts for the particular play and can reuse the same template for all the different plays.

Comment: I think you can do it easily, but going through your verbose description and trying to figure out what you meant is a real pain. Why don't you post your inventory file, the playbook and ask to fill the part in question?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault for trying to still wrap groups['FOO'] with the quotes. I was able to set a variable inside the playbook and pass it down by doing the following:

```
- name: Big Tree Stitch Kafka
  hosts: kafka-bts
  vars:
    kafka_hosts: "kafka-bts"
  remote_user: centos
  become_user: root
  become: yes
  roles:
    - { role: kafka }
```

And then having this in my jinja template.

```
% for url in groups[kafka-bts] %}
  {%- if url == ansible_fqdn or url in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
     or ( kafka_id is defined and loop.index0 == kafka_id | int ) -%}
        broker.id={{loop.index0}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```